# Alteração de célula específica em MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Bom, estou tentando alterar apenas uma célula específica em MySQL usando um formulário em PHP, porém, não consigo realizar tal ação e nenhum erro é mostrado para que eu tente repará-lo, como posso corrigir o problema?

> Lógica

```
<?php

require("conecta.php");

$novoTituloDisciplina = $_POST["novo-titulo-disciplina"];
$valorDisciplina = $_POST["disciplina-a-alterar"];

$query = "update table disciplinas set 'nome_disciplina' = '{$novoTituloDisciplina}' where id = '{$valorDisciplina}'";

if(mysqli_query($conexao, $query)){
    mysqli_close();
    header("Location:../cadastra_novo.php");
}else{
    mysqli_close();
    header("Location:../index.php");
};
```

> Formulário

```
<form action="logicas/logica-altera_disciplina.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <h3>Alterar Disciplina</h3>
    </div>
    <label>Disciplina</label>
    <select name="disciplina-a-alterar">
        <option disabled selected>-Selecione a disciplina-</option>
        <!-- Receber as opções disponíveis no banco de dados -->
        <?php
        $disciplinas = listagemDisciplinas($conexao);
        foreach ($disciplinas as $disciplina){
            ?>
            <option value="<?= $disciplina["id"] ?>"><?= $disciplina["nome_disciplina"] ?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <label>Novo nome</label>
    <input type="text" name="novo-titulo-disciplina">

    <button type="submit">Alterar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro esta na sua `query`, para executar um update não precisa da palavra `table`, ficaria assim:

```
$query = "update disciplinas set 'nome_disciplina' = '{$novoTituloDisciplina}' where id = '{$valorDisciplina}'";
```

Comment: foi o que acabei de fazer aqui, vim excluir a pergunta, mas como deu a resposta correta, logo volto para dar como resposta